# How can I make a Qt widget ignore style sheets set on parent widgets?

Tags: qt, parent-child, qtstylesheets

When adding a QComboBox control in Qt Designer, I get a terrible looking, non-native control:

[image]

On digging further, it turns out that two of the parent controls, QParentWindow and QStackedWidget, have style sheets that QComboBox is inheriting.  If I delete the custom styles, then I get a native QComboBox like the one on the left.

How can I have QComboBox (and widgets generally) NOT inherit parent styles?  Or, how can I create a style for, say, QParentWindow, and do it so that it's local only and does not cascade?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can prevent it from cascading. But by using more specific [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) in your stylesheet, maybe you could define properties only for your QParentWindow class or specific object.

Comment: Agreed. Instead of using generics in your stylesheet, make it specific to only the QWidgets you want to style.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.  It seems that using the following specific selector syntax QWidget#my_container_name *will* indeed keep the style local to the QWidget whose name is my_container_name and prevents it from cascading.

Answer (score 5):

you need to define a style and then assign it to that object:

```
QString settingStyle = " QGroupBox#groupBoxSettings {\
        background-color: rgb(248,248,248);\
        border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 255);\
        border-radius: 3px;\
        border-color:rgb(170, 170, 255);\
}";


ui->groupBoxSettings->setStyleSheet(settingStyle);
```

here "groupBoxSettings" is the object name. This way any thing inside the groupbox they'll have their own style.

Comment: Thanks for giving an example. One can even leave the `QGroupBox` out as long as the object names (set by `setObjectName`) are unique. Especially if there would stand `QWidget#...` it would be pretty useless because most/every widget is derived from `QWidget`.